# Turn off template suggestion for specific fields

Tags: 8, theming

I have the problem, that the theme / template suggestion comments destroy the html when they are outputted as values.

```
{% set img_uri = "fields.img.value"%}

{{ dpm(img_uri)
style="backround:url({{ createMyImagePathCustomTwigFunction(img_uri) }});"
```

Results in:

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'views_view_field' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/views/views-view-field.html.twig' -->
public://img/person/joshua-ness-117255-unsplash_0.jpg 
<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/views/views-view-field.html.twig' -->


<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/views/views-view-fields.html.twig' -->
```

..as wrong uri.

I know that I could dive deeper into the rendered array to find other versions.

However:
To change production templates in general only for enabling a developing environment seems wrong to me.

Better would be a hook that would remove field tpl suggestions in general as I don't need them.

I know I can write handler functions... that is what I do in the moment.

But cleaner would be to turn the suggestions off for views fields. How this can be done?

Comment: How did you turn them on? Apart from that, they should be disabled at all in production environments.

Comment: Sure but they are wrong in dev. As you read in my question I would have to create handler functions which are just used in dev. In Production theme suggestions are anyway not used.

My question is not how to turn them off in general - of course I know that. ;)
I need to turn them off for views fields only - so that I don't have to create a twig "filter comments out"- function that wraps all values as they might have or not have comments in them.

Comment: In this moment I create overhead in production.That is something I want to avoid.

Comment: Turning template suggestions off here is just curing a symptom which is caused by a deeper problem. You should focus on Twig. That's where you put an error. Looking at your question I already see two at a glance. One of them is that you seem to dump variables inside some tag, which probably is the root of your problem. Fix this and then you can delete your question.

Comment: @leymannx In the moment I really create messy html/twig script, because I need to do the following with each value:
value | remove_html_comments |replace({"\n": "", "\r\n": "", "\t": "", "\n\r": "", " ":""}) | raw. This is just not right. :)

Comment: Just have seen this: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2672656 Seems that this is the way to go... hell no :)

Comment: That's interesting indeed. As quickfix I'd simply preprocess me that file path into the template as raw string, and remove any of your custom functions out of Twig.

Comment: Just make the url a string as he said. Far easier.

Comment: I need the uri. I need it to dynamically produce a couple of image styles url's for responsive images. As long there is no easy way to turn the url's back to uri's I it is easier my way.

Comment: Also the problem will still be present - for each value. Id's, background-url's and so on. I need clean values and no in comments wrapped html elements.

Comment: Please don't add your answer to your question. Simply answer your own question properly. Even if this is just a workaround for now I guess it can help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems, that there is no solid alternative that works for field values I have written a Twig-Filter which returns the value via this php function:

```
public function removeHtmlComments($string) {

  $output = preg_replace(array('/<!--(.|\s)*?-->\s*/', '/\t+/', '/\n+/', '/[\r\n]/', '/[\n\r]/'), '', $string);

  return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You try this code :

```
{% set img_uri = "fields.img.value"%}

{{ dpm(img_uri)
style="backround:url({{ createMyImagePathCustomTwigFunction(img_uri) |render|striptags}});"
```

use |render|striptags

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked well in the Twig was to use : `field | render | striptags | trim`

- striptags : remove the suggestions (or any other html tag)
- trim : remove the white-spaces left after striptags

Answer (score -1):

Try the following.

```
{{ file_url(fields.img.content|striptags|trim) }}
```